# Spotify Developer API on Blackberry QNX

Tags: blackberry-playbook, spotify, qnx

Is it possible to use the Spotify Developer API on QNX, Blackberry??
I would like to create a simple Spotify Client for my Playbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no build of libspotify compatible with QNX.

Comment: I just saw your profile and you seem to be very close to the source... Do you think it would be a lot of effort to port lispotify to QNX? It is fully Posix! Lots of libs has been ported to the system, see here: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/10/open-source-playbook-os/ Cheers!